# How to Apply alpha/texture to the entire object

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, texture-painting

I am trying to apply this alpha/texture to my object without manually painting with the brush, as in some areas it comes out with larger dimensions or undesired shapes at the corners. I have attempted to use nodes such as an alpha image and then a color mix, but it did not work. Additionally, I would like only the body, excluding certain parts such as the eyes or limbs.
[image]

Comment: the problem is most likely because of your unwrapping. You'll  probably need to unwrap the model by hand and after that it should be fine. Applying specific texture only to a part of you model is no problem. just select faces you want and in material tab add a new material and assign

Comment: Hello, Qatawneh.. welcome. A shot of your UV map would help us help you, here, I think, we can see  if @JiříHonzák is right.